# AngularFire Observable to trigger when stopped changing

Tags: rxjs, angularfire

I would like to be notified in my subscribing client when a value in my Firebase database hasn't changed for 3 seconds. I'm using RxJs & AngularFire in Typescript. I'm new to Rx in general and I've tried different combinations of Timeout, Delay and Throttle. It seems [AngularFire Observable](https://angularfire2.com/api/classes/_utils_firebase_object_observable_.firebaseobjectobservable.html) doesn't inherit the full RX Observable interface, otherwise I suppose I should use interval. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  angularFireStream$,
  angularFireStream$
    .switchMapTo(
      Rx.Observable.of("no change in last 3s").delay(3000)
    )
)
```

---

Live example:

```js
let angularFireStream$ = new Rx.Subject();
    
Rx.Observable.merge(
  angularFireStream$,
  angularFireStream$
  .switchMapTo(
    Rx.Observable.of("no change in last 3s").delay(3000)
  )
)
.subscribe(console.log);


angularFireStream$.next(1);
setTimeout(() => angularFireStream$.next(2), 2000)
setTimeout(() => angularFireStream$.next(3), 3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```